# Struts 2 optiontransferselect cannot use < symbol in addToLeftLabel attribute

Tags: eclipse, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I am trying to change the text of **add to left button** become `<`. What I have tried is

```jsp
<s:optiontransferselect
    label="Favourite Cartoons Characters"
    name="leftSide"
    addToLeftLabel="&lt;"
    list="{'Master', 'Chief Officer', '2nd Officer'}"
    doubleName="rightSide"
    doubleList="{}"
/>
```

But instead of changing the button text to `<` it shows `&lt;` instead.

But when I did it like this

```
<s:optiontransferselect
    label="Favourite Cartoons Characters"
    name="leftSide"
    addToLeftLabel="<"
    list="{'Master', 'Chief Officer', '2nd Officer'}"
    doubleName="rightSide"
    doubleList="{}"
/>
```

It works fine but in Eclipse the code linter doesn't work anymore after the line where I used `<`

Is there anything that I can do to bring back the linting or use `&lt;` in the code?

Comment: The `<` will probably show error in your ide, but it should work.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without causing error in ide?

Comment: Just curiousity.. And the code error detection wont work for the rest of the file after the tag.

Comment: @AgusZendy For curiosity you should know that you can't use empty brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```jsp
addToLeftLabel="<"
```

and it works well.

Many IDEs have JSP editors that generate errors in JSP because they don't understand specific EL languages and always mistake to choose one that they want to use for their errors.

Comment: How EL is related?

Comment: @AleksandrM `{}`  is used in EL.